# The title attribute of "a tag" is displayed in separate lines

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to display the content in the title attribute of "a tag" in separate lines.

But in browsers it is treated as string output.

```rb
# HTML
<%= link_to filipino_url(f), remote: true, method: :get, class: 'client-link', title: "Error： #{f.error_messages.split(';').join(';&#10;')}" do %>
  <i class='fa fa-exclamation-circle text-danger'></i>
  <%= f.full_name %>
<% end %>
```

```html
<!-- Developer mode of browser(F12) -->
<a class="client-link" title="Error： xxx1ooo;&#10;xxx2ooo" data-remote="true" data-method="get" href="http://localhost:4000/filipinoes/1">
  ......
</a>
```

```
# I got it.
"Error： xxx1ooo;&#10;xxx2ooo"
# But I need it.
"Error： xxx1ooo;
         xxx2ooo"
```

I used the developer mode of the browser to modify it. After pressing the Enter key, I got the effect I needed. They were displayed in separate lines.

But through the program output, it becomes a string, and the browser does not parse the symbols.

I don't know what went wrong. Please help me.

Comment: Try to join with `\n` (or `\t\n` to indent): `"Error： #{f.error_messages.split(';').join('\n')}"`

Comment: @CAmador ,Thank you for your answer, but I've tried that these are not tokens for line breaks in Title attributes.

Comment: Try this instead: `title="Error：&#10;  xxx1ooo;&#10;  xxx2ooo"`

Comment: @Surya ,Thank you for your reply. It's still impossible to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used another solution to solve this problem.
Use another tag on the periphery to replace the "a tag" prompt function

```
<% if f.error_status.error? %>
  <td title="Error：&#10;<%= raw f.error_messages.split(';').join(';&#10;') %>">
    <%= link_to filipino_url(f), remote: true, method: :get, class: 'client-link' do %>
      <i class='fa fa-exclamation-circle text-danger'></i>
      <%= f.full_name %>
    <% end %>
  </td>
<% else %>
```

This is not a good way to solve the problem.
But I really can't think of any better way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

[HTML 5 specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/html51/dom.html#the-title-attribute) mentions that you can actually use `"\n"`:

```
title: "Error： #{f.error_messages.split(';').join("\n")}"
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried this way, but it didn't work.

Comment: @XueSong_Zhang with double-quotes `"`?

Comment: I tried single and double quotation marks, but they still didn't work.

Comment: I may need to use "html_self" or "raw", but I don't know how to use "raw" in "link_to".
So I used the solution in the following reply